# How can I rebind .click() functions after .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('a').click(function() {
    _link = $(this).attr('href');
    loadContent(_link);
    return false;
});

function loadContent(href){
    $('#content').load(href + ' #content > *)
}
```

I have all `<a>` binded with a `.click()` that will only change the contents of `#content`. However,  new `<a>` from the new `#content` arent working with the previous `.click()` function. How can I rebind it?

Adding the function again after the `.load()` seems to work

```
function loadContent(href){
    $('#content').load(href + ' #content > *);

    $('a').click(function() {
      _link = $(this).attr('href');
      loadContent(_link);
      return false;
    });
}
```

But would this mess up the `s' that were already binded and cause it to run it on a loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind events to dynamically added elements (in this case `a`s):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    _link = $(this).attr('href');
    loadContent(_link);
    return false;
});
```

Event delegation works by listening for events bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor (`document` is the best default if none is handy, do not use `'body'` as it has click bugs relating to styling). It *then* applies the jQuery selector to the elements in the bubble chain, it *then* applies your function *to the matching element(s) that caused the event*. The advantage is that the elements only need to exist at event time and now when the handler was registered.

Comment: `document` is the usual choice for a delegated event if a closer non-changing ancestor is not available. It has the extra advantage of always being present, event without a DOM ready event wrapper.

Comment: technically - you bind the event handler to a higher element so that element listens for events from it's descendants

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ: Hence `"if a closer non-changing ancestor is not available"`. For efficiency the target should be the closest ancestor that is not a dynamic element, but the speed difference is pretty much 0 as the bubbling is quite efficient (and we don't `click` 50,0000 times a second) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes.. but `Use event delegation to bind dynamically added a elements:` sounds misleading

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ: I have now described delegated events more completely. That OK now?

Answer (score 1):

When you initially add the click event listener, it is only bound to the existing anchor tags. The code to bind the event listener is run once and does not run again for any new anchor tags.

You can try attaching a listener to the body for click events on any anchor tags.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function() {...});
```

Comment: Avoid using `'body'` for delegated events. It has isues related to styling especially with click events. Use `document` if a closer non-changing ancestor is not available.

Comment: @TrueBlue: does it? Could you offer any references? (I'm not intending to disagree with your statement, but this is the first time I've heard of such a thing, and now I'm curious...)

Comment: @David Thomas:As a test, try create a page where the `body` only has absolute positioned elements. You will not get a click event on the `body` using delegated click (as the body has a calculated height of 0), but `document` will work.

Comment: @TrueBlue: that makes sense, I think I interpreted your sentence originally as "using `body` for event-delegation *interferes with styling*" as opposed to your (apparent) intention that "*styling can interfere with the use of `body`* for event delegation."